# Vertical and Horizontal Allignment in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextpane, text-alignment

I am trying to insert a value in a JTable. But I come across some issues(Design). When I tried to add a value normally word/Line wrapping is not working, so I tried inserting the value embedded with HTML tag

```
<html>Value</html>
```

but the issue with this is there occurs some extra space on top(the first line comes exactly middle). So I tried with adding JTextpane to the JTable using renderer but it only makes horizontal center and not vertical center(Word/Line wrapping is working correctly).

In short my needs are

1. I need to enter a value in JTable.
2. I need to Word/Line Wrap if it exceeds the column width.
3. I need the value to be displayed exactly in middle of cell(Horizontally and vertically centered)

   ```
   class TableCellLongTextRenderer extends JTextPane implements TableCellRenderer {    
   @Override
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
       this.setText((String) value);
       StyledDocument doc = this.getStyledDocument();
       SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
       StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
       StyleConstants.setSpaceAbove(center, StyleConstants.getSpaceBelow(center) / 2);
       StyleConstants.setSpaceBelow(center, StyleConstants.getSpaceAbove(center));
       doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
       return this;
   }}
   ```

   What is wrong in my code can someone help me to rectify it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you can use a `JLabel` and `<HTML>` to render it?

Comment: As in my question I tried to embed value with html tag is it enough? According to my knowledge every cell in JTable is Jlabel. So adding html tag directly and rendering may be same right? Pardon me if I said anything wrong.

Comment: That would be the first thing you tried

Comment: According to my knowledge every cell in JTable is Jlabel. So is there any difference in adding html tag directly to the value that we are going to insert and rendering the JTable?

Comment: Adding `html` around the text allows the label to auto wrap lines of text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use plain `HTML` and the default `TableCellRenderer`, which is based on a `JLabel` to achieve this basic principles.

The following example uses a `html` `table`, which further aligns the text (broken of lines) to the center of the label.  It uses the `horizontalAlignment` and `verticalAlignment` properties of the `JLabel` to get the contents aligned within the label.

It also does a little trickery with the row height ;)

[image: Table with html]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                String text
                                = "<html><div align=center>"
                                + "And Caesar's spirit, raging for revenge,<br>"
                                + "With Ate by his side come hot from hell,<br>"
                                + "Shall in these confines with a monarch's voice<br>"
                                + "Cry \"Havoc!\" and let slip the dogs of war,<br>"
                                + "That this foul deed shall smell above the earth<br>"
                                + "With carrion men, groaning for burial.";

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
                model.addRow(new String[]{text});

                JTable table = new JTable(model) {
                    @Override
                    public int getRowHeight(int row) {
                        Component comp = prepareRenderer(getCellRenderer(row, 0), row, 0);
                        return comp.getPreferredSize().height;
                    }
                };
                ((JLabel)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                ((JLabel)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                table.setRowHeight(100);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now, I pre-wrapped my text and applied it to the model.  You could create a custom `TableCellRenderer` (using a `DefaultTableCellRenderer`) and post-wrap the text, depending on your needs

Comment: You code exacly worked for me with one column and one row. I edited DefaultTableModel(0, 1) to DefaultTableModel(0, 2) and added the second column value with different size. But the row consumes the height of first cell, and  according to my need my row size is fixed to 70. So when i remove the lines to get component height also i didn't get the desired output. Please help me :( .

Comment: You see the `getRowHeight` method I overrode from `JTable`?  You will want to calculate the height of each cell in the row and return the highest