# Wrapping Line, Right Align,Auto Resize Row Height In JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I write a Java application and I need to a object of class `JTable` that has some features :

1. Auto wrapping line
2. Right alignment
3. Auto resize row height (This means for example size of a row is 25 but size of another row in table is 50 with content size of a row)
4. Speed of rendering **must be** high

But my code does not work fast and has not top features completely, I am write a minimal version of my application in last of question:

This is my gui class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private BankTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public GUI(){
        super("Bank Table");
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPanel);
        contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,700));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        makeTable();

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(50);

        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void makeTable(){
        String[][]data= new String[][]{{"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/01"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/02"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/03"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/04"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/05"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/06"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/07"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/08"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/09"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/10"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/11"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/12"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/13"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/14"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/15"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/16"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/17"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081111111111111111111111111111111111634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/18"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081222222222222222222222222222634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/19"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/20"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/21"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/22"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/23"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/24"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/25"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/26"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/27"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/28"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/29"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/30"}};

        String[] columns= new String[]{"شماره حساب", "اطلاعات اضافه", "مانده","واریز","برداشت","فیش/ حواله","کد شعبه","شرح","ساعت","تاریخ"};

        table = new BankTable(data,columns);
        table.updateRowHeights();
        System.out.println("Table");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        GUI gui = new GUI();
    }

}
```

This is render of table :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TextAreaRenderer extends JTextArea
        implements TableCellRenderer {

    public TextAreaRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);    

        setEditable(false);
        setCursor(null);
        setOpaque(false);
        setFocusable(false);
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);

    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable,
                                                   Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                                                   int column) {
        setText((String)obj);
        setFont(new Font("bnazanin", Font.BOLD, 15));

        return this;
    }    
}
```

And This is table class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;

public class BankTable extends JTable {

    public BankTable(String[][] data,String[] columns){
        super(data,columns);

        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        setBounds(60,80,400,600);

        changeTableHeader();

        DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

        TextAreaRenderer textAreaRenderer = new TextAreaRenderer();

        for(int i=0 ; i<columns.length ; i++){
            getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(textAreaRenderer);
        }    
    }

    public void changeTableHeader(){
        getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(57,77,112));
        getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Calibri Light", Font.BOLD, 20));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }

    public void updateRowHeights()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            int rowHeight = getRowHeight();

            for (int column = 0; column < getColumnCount(); column++)
            {
                Component comp = prepareRenderer(getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
            }
            setRowHeight(row, rowHeight + 20);
        }
    }    
}
```

**EDIT:**
  [This is a simple for my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD6Im.png)

Comment: *"Autowrapper"* - [Java-Swing adding multiple lines in jtable's cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042605/java-swing-adding-multiple-lines-in-jtables-cell/31043203#31043203)

Comment: *"Right alignment"* - [`JLabel#setHorizontalAlignment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalAlignment-int-)

Comment: *"Auto resize row height"* - [Vertical and Horizontal Allignment in JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912426/vertical-and-horizontal-allignment-in-jtextpane/31912962#31912962)

Comment: My code has auto wrapping cell however I used this code previous but speed of rendering did not solve in both code. @MadProgrammer

Comment: *"Speed of rendering must be high"* - Well, that's going to be an issue, because for EVERY row, you need calculate the height of each column and determine the height the row needs.  This should be done sparingly and only when you absolute need it - such as when the model is changed or when the model itself changes or the `JTable` is invalidated. You will then need to cache the results so that any future rendering can be done quickly

Comment: I would consider using a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and wrap the text in `HTML` blocks, as the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` is already optimised - check out it's implementation if you want to see more details. For example `setFont(new Font("bnazanin", Font.BOLD, 15));` would be an expensive call to make EVERY time a cell was rendered

Comment: I need to many features that I wrote in question. and I am funded every feature separately . but when I write this code that has many features ,speed of rendering becomes slow. @MadProgrammer If you can improved my code or write a new code... thanks

Comment: I tried a `DefultTableCellRenderer` and change data to html previous. when I comment this line  `setFont(new Font("bnazanin", Font.BOLD, 15));` my problem does not solved.@MadProgrammer can try this code and change code yourself and post your answer?

Comment: It seems to render just fine for me - what are you comparing it to?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Try this code and it is OK?!!! When I scroll table program has lag... I like when scroll table speed of rendering equals to when I use `JLable` for render.

Answer (score 2):

For what is worth here is some old code I had lying around.

It uses a JTextArea with wrapping but limits the lines in the text area to 2 lines. You can then scroll the text area to see the other lines.

Maybe this type of approach will help with your requirement?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableTextArea extends JFrame
{
    public TableTextArea()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(40, 5);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setRowHeight(40);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 0, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 1, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 0, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 2, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 3, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 4, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 5, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 6, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 7, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 8, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 9, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 10, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 11, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 12, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 13, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 14, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 15, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 16, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 17, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 18, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 19, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 20, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 21, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 22, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 23, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 24, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 25, 4);
        table.setValueAt("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 26, 2);
        table.setValueAt("aaa bbb ccccc dddd eeee fff ggggg hhhhh iiii jjj", 27, 2);
        table.setValueAt("1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999 0000", 28, 4);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );

        //  Override default renderer for a specific column

        TableCellRenderer renderer = new TextAreaRenderer();
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer( renderer );
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer( renderer );
        table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                TableTextArea frame = new TableTextArea();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    **
    */
    class TextAreaRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
    {
        private JTextArea renderTextArea;
        private JScrollPane renderScrollPane;
        private JTextArea focusTextArea;
        private JScrollPane focusScrollPane;
        private boolean firstTime = true;

        public TextAreaRenderer()
        {
            renderTextArea = new JTextArea();
            renderTextArea.setEditable( false );
            renderTextArea.setLineWrap( true );
            renderTextArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
            renderScrollPane = new JScrollPane( renderTextArea );
            renderScrollPane.setBorder(null);
            renderScrollPane.revalidate();

            focusTextArea = new JTextArea();
            focusTextArea.setEditable( false );
            focusTextArea.setLineWrap( true );
            focusTextArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
            focusScrollPane = new JScrollPane( focusTextArea );
            focusScrollPane.setBorder(null);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            final JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, final int row, final int column)
        {
            //  For some reason the scrollbars don't appear on the first cell renderered.
            //  Forcing a repaint of the cell seems to fix the problem.

            if (firstTime)
            {
                firstTime = false;
                Rectangle cellRectangle = table.getCellRect(row, column, false);
//              renderScrollPane.setBounds(cellRectangle);
//              table.add(renderScrollPane);
//              renderScrollPane.revalidate();
                table.repaint(cellRectangle);
            }

            System.out.println(row + " :: " + column + " : " + hasFocus);
            table.remove(focusScrollPane);

            renderTextArea.setText( value != null ? value.toString() : "" );
            renderTextArea.setCaretPosition(0);

            if (hasFocus)
            {
                renderTextArea.setBackground( table.getSelectionBackground() );

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        addRealTextAreaToTable(table, row, column);
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (isSelected)
                renderTextArea.setBackground( table.getSelectionBackground() );
            else
                renderTextArea.setBackground( table.getBackground() );

            return renderScrollPane;
        }

        private void addRealTextAreaToTable(JTable table, int row, int column)
        {
            System.out.println(row + " :: " + column);
            Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
            focusTextArea.setText( value != null ? value.toString() : "" );
            focusTextArea.setCaretPosition(0);
//          focusTextArea.setBackground( table.getBackground() );
            focusTextArea.setBackground( table.getSelectionBackground() );
            Rectangle cellRectangle = table.getCellRect(row, column, false);
            focusScrollPane.setBounds(cellRectangle);
            table.add(focusScrollPane);
            focusScrollPane.revalidate();
            focusTextArea.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tanks for trying but this code is bad because I want size of row changes automatically  **not** like your code has a scroll in some cells. please look to simple table that I upload to question at now

Answer (score 1):

So, I've spent a bit of time banging my head against this trying a verity of different things.

Starting with `TextAreaRenderer`.  I'd prefer to use the `DefaultTableCelllRenderer`, but after playing around with that, I wasn't able to get it to work satisfactorily.  So, instead, I took most of it's own optimisations and applied them to the `TextAreaRenderer` itself.

One of things you really want to do is reduce the amount changes that each `getTableCellRendererComponent` will make.  `JTextArea` is already a complex component.

I removed the `setOpaque` call and moved the `setFont` call to the constructor.  I also added selection support (it was part of my testing)

```
public class TextAreaRenderer extends JTextArea
        implements TableCellRenderer {

    public TextAreaRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        setEditable(false);
        setCursor(null);
        //setOpaque(false);
        setFocusable(false);
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setFont(new Font("bnazanin", Font.BOLD, 15));

        getCaret().setBlinkRate(0);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable,
            Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        setText((String) obj);

        if (isSelected) {
            System.out.println("!!Selected");
            setBackground(jTable.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(jTable.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            setBackground(jTable.getBackground());
            setForeground(jTable.getForeground());
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Overridden for performance reasons. See the
     * <a href="#override">Implementation Note</a>
     * for more information.
     */
    public boolean isOpaque() {
        Color back = getBackground();
        Component p = getParent();
        if (p != null) {
            p = p.getParent();
        }

        // p should now be the JTable.
        boolean colorMatch = (back != null) && (p != null)
                && back.equals(p.getBackground())
                && p.isOpaque();
        return !colorMatch && super.isOpaque();
    }

    /**
     * Overridden for performance reasons. See the
     * <a href="#override">Implementation Note</a>
     * for more information.
     *
     * @since 1.5
     */
    public void invalidate() {
    }

    /**
     * Overridden for performance reasons. See the
     * <a href="#override">Implementation Note</a>
     * for more information.
     */
    public void validate() {
    }

    /**
     * Overridden for performance reasons. See the
     * <a href="#override">Implementation Note</a>
     * for more information.
     */
    public void revalidate() {
    }

    /**
     * Overridden for performance reasons. See the
     * <a href="#override">Implementation Note</a>
     * for more information.
     */
    public void repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    }

    /**
     * Overridden for performance reasons. See the
     * <a href="#override">Implementation Note</a>
     * for more information.
     */
    public void repaint(Rectangle r) {
    }

    /**
     * Overridden for performance reasons. See the
     * <a href="#override">Implementation Note</a>
     * for more information.
     *
     * @since 1.5
     */
    public void repaint() {
    }

    /**
     * Overridden for performance reasons. See the
     * <a href="#override">Implementation Note</a>
     * for more information.
     */
    public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue) {
    }

}
```

I then attacked the `BlankTable`...

One of the big changes is the table is now capable of calculating the height of the rows dynamically.  Because the calculation is expensive, the result of this operation is cached.  The problem, though, is the `JTable` also has it's own internal cache ... which is private  ... so rather then tracking down the reflection route, we need to provide some compensation to circumvent some of the side effects this API creates.

When calling `setRowHeight`, the `JTable` call `invalidate` and `repaint` itself.  When we're performing our calculations we'd like to stop this, but there are some circumstances under which we should still allow to work (such as when the columns are resized and the `JTable` is `invalidated`)

```
public class BankTable extends JTable {

    public BankTable(String[][] data, String[] columns) {
        super(data, columns);

        changeTableHeader();

        setGridColor(Color.RED);

        TableCellRenderer textAreaRenderer = new TextAreaRenderer();

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(textAreaRenderer);
        }
    }

    public void changeTableHeader() {
        getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(57, 77, 112));
        getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Calibri Light", Font.BOLD, 20));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }

    private Map<Integer, Integer> rowMap = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean quietUpdate = false;
    private boolean forceUpdate = false;

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        rowMap.clear();
        forceUpdate = true;
        super.invalidate();
        forceUpdate = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void resizeAndRepaint() {
        if (quietUpdate) {
            if (forceUpdate) {
                super.resizeAndRepaint();
            }
        } else {
            super.resizeAndRepaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowHeight(int row) {
        Integer rowHeight = rowMap.get(row);
        if (rowHeight == null) {
            TableColumnModel model = getColumnModel();
            rowHeight = getRowHeight();
            for (int column = 0; column < getColumnCount(); column++) {
                int colWidth = model.getColumn(column).getWidth();
                Component comp = prepareRenderer(getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                comp.setSize(new Dimension(colWidth, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
            }
            rowMap.put(row, rowHeight);
            quietUpdate = true;
            setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
            quietUpdate = false;
        }
        return rowHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        if (rowMap == null) {
            super.tableChanged(e);
            return;
        }
        if (e == null || e.getFirstRow() == TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW) {
            rowMap.clear();
            super.tableChanged(e);
            return;
        }

        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.INSERT) {
            super.tableChanged(e);
            return;
        }

        int modelColumn = e.getColumn();
        int start = e.getFirstRow();
        int end = e.getLastRow();

        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.DELETE || e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
            for (int row = start; row <= end; row++) {
                rowMap.remove(row);
            }
            super.tableChanged(e);
            return;
        }

        if (end == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            rowMap.clear();
        }
        super.tableChanged(e); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

There are still a few other areas which might need further optimising (I've not tested a sorted table, so `tableChanged` which need to be updated and I've not tested for changes to a cell either)

After the initial load, I've found the rendering to be reasonable.  Because of the component in use, the font and other system issues, you're milage may fair.

Comment: This table has all features that I need but speed of rendering at now very low. so problem does not solve.  however answer code in bottom link with many changes operate very well... but JTable itself does not good for complex using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797852/making-table-with-list-of-jpanels

Comment: Gee, the rendering was much improved over your original for me - not sure what you're doing

Comment: I tested your code and however was improved but speed of rendering is slow still.

Comment: I'm not sure compared to what. Generally my testing had the speed at a reasonable level no more or less then I would normally experience - although the solution is more complex then most things I need to do - so long as you were just scrolling, things got messy for a short period when resizing the table/columns, but (for me) was an expected overhead for the need to recalculate the row heights. Text layout is already a complex process. I would consider trying to reduce the complexity of the over all solution and re-introduce them in small increments to see where some issues might appear

Comment: OK. tanks anyway. but I need to more speed... :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your contribution. This solution is, in my case, amazing! Congratulations!